# Количество сотрудников / три таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Нужно вывести SQL запросом список отделов автосервиса с количеством работников. Поля для отображения - PersonDepartmentName, CountPersonWorkPlace. Отсортировать по CountPersonWorkPlace.
Прикрепляю всё, что связано с этим:
[image: Таблица Person]

[image: Таблица PersonWorkPlace]
[image: Таблица PersonDepartment]

Сам пытался связывать таблицы, но количество так и не получилось вывести.

Comment: Бред который выходил:
SELECT PersonDepartmentName, COUNT(PersonWorkPlace.PersonWorkPlaceID) AS NU FROM PersonDepartment 
JOIN Person ON PersonDepartment.PersonDepartmentID=Person.PersonID
JOIN PersonWorkPlace ON PersonDepartment.PersonDepartmentID=PersonWorkPlace.PersonWorkPlaceID
JOIN PersonPost ON PersonDepartment.PersonDepartmentID=PersonPost.PersonPostID

Comment: так как Вы написали запрос, так он точно работать не будет, надо групировать.

Answer (score 0):

using group by:

```
select
    distinct pd.PersonDepartmentName,
    count(p.PersonID) as CountPersonWorkPlace
  from Person p
  left join PersonWorkPlace pwp on p.PersonID = pwp.PersonID
  left join PersonDepartament pd on pwp.PersonDepartamentID = pd.PersonDepartamentID
  group by pd.PersonDepartmentName
  order by CountPersonWorkPlace asc;
```

using analytical functions (window functions):

```
select
    distinct pd.PersonDepartmentName,
    count(p.PersonID) over(partition by pd.PersonDepartmentName) as CountPersonWorkPlace
  from Person p
  left join PersonWorkPlace pwp on p.PersonID = pwp.PersonID
  left join PersonDepartament pd on pwp.PersonDepartamentID = pd.PersonDepartamentID
  order by CountPersonWorkPlace asc;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the force of GROUP BY, Luke:

```
SELECT pd.PersonDepartmentName, COUNT(*) AS NU
FROM PersonDepartment AS pd
  JOIN Person AS p ON p.PersonDepartmentID=pd.PersonDepartmentID
GROUP BY pd.PersonDepartmentName
```

Comment: Выводит почему-то неверное количество и сортировать нужно по CountPersonWorkPlace :(